# Using DbGeography with EF6 + SqlServerCe.4.0 (.sdf database). Theoretically possible but not working

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, spatial

According to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417.aspx, it is possible to use "DbGeography", because it will be mapped to "image" in the database side. (As when using enums, they are mapped to ints)

However,

If I have this:

```
public class Something
{
    public long SomethingId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

When the database is created for the first time (using EF6 with "Code First" approach), I get this exception:

```
There is no store type corresponding to the EDM type 'Edm.Geography(Nullable=True)' of primitive type 'Geography'.
```

My connection string is the following:

```
<add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

**What am I doing wrong?**
I checked and my EF's dll is version 6

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, the MSDN article Refers to the fact that the replication component move data in this column type to a "image" column in SQL Compact.

You must use:

```
[MaxLength]
public byte[] Location { get; set; }
```

to store the data, and use the Spatial libraries to convert back and forth in your app

Comment: Can I do those castings in pure Linq To Entities? Eg. myDbContext.Persons.Where(p => (DbGeography)p.Location ... ) ? Or I will need .ToList() in between?

Comment: ToList would be required, yes

Comment: I cant bring all rows to memory! do you suggest any solution? maybe a pure SQL query? (instead of LINQ).

Comment: Not possible with SQL Compact, as it does not have any spatial support. You can fetch in batches (using Skip/Take)